# Need help understanding the structure of this insertion method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am working on a homework assignment involving array sorting methods, we are given the methods, and I'm having a little trouble understanding how this insertion sort method functions. More specifically, the role the two variables passed to the method play.

As I understand, the Key variable describes the index of the array that you'd like to place your inserted number in and the item is the number itself. Within main, I simply request the user to enter two numbers and pass them to the method, one for the key and the other for the item. Here is the given code for this segment:

```
public final void insertion(double Key, double Item)
{
    if (arraySize == 0)
    {
        arr[0] = Item;
    }
    /* find the position for inserting the given item */
    int position = 0;
    while (position < arraySize &  Key > arr[position])
    {
        position++;
    }
    for (int i = arraySize; i > position; i--)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }
    arr[position] = Item;
    arraySize = arraySize + 1;

}
```

However, when I pass doubles to the method as I have explained, I get an error stating that index (array length) is out of bounds for length (array length).

Clearly, I am misunderstanding the purpose or structure of this method and I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. I know this is a very simple problem.

EDIT: Here is how I initialize my array, the given code is in a separate class from my main method:

```
    public static double[] arr;
    private int arraySize;

    public sortedArrayAccess(int scale)
    {
        arr = new double[scale];
        arraySize = arr.length;
    }
```

Within my main method:

```
    System.out.print("Enter an array size: ");
    int d = sc.nextInt();
    sortedArrayAccess test = new sortedArrayAccess(d);
    for(int i=0;i<test.arr.length;i++)
        {
        System.out.print("Enter a number for index " + i + ": ");
        double c = sc.nextDouble();
        test.arr[i] = c;
        }
```

Comment: The method signature is indeed strange. It would only work as advertised if `Key` is always the same value as `Item`.

Comment: That is what I thought! I figured I must be wrong though... and I am hesitant to alter the given code as that is outside the scope of my assignment and it is very likely the professor will deduct points for any alterations.

Comment: Ask your professor about it. The two parameters don't make sense.

Comment: I will discuss it further with him tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How do you initialize ‘arr’ variable?

Anyway the problem is that when you create the array - you should specify initial capacity. And every time when you add the element into array you are about to increase it.
When you try to ask for for a cell of array indexed i if array capacity is less then I - you’ll be given the arrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I have updated my post with my array initialization code!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if (arraySize == 0)
{
    arr[0] = Item;
}
```

You are assigning the Item to the first element in the array. But the array size must be empty as stated by the `if (arraySize == 0)`

So you have two options:

- adjust the size of the array (by creating a new one)
- or return an error

Comment: I changed that portion to spit an error out at array size 0 and to assign item variable to arr[0] if it is only of size 1 and still received the same error. I should never have been tripping that code block though, as my arrays were always greater than 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (arraySize == 0)
    {
        arr[0] = Item;
    }
```

As you know, in computer science, indices starts from 0. Which means arr[0] here is the first slot of your array. if arraySize is 0, there is no such index arr[0]. Your code tries to insert the Item to zero sized array. This causes Index out of bound exception.

By the way, If it is a sorting algorithm for the values, "Key" variable is not required. You can delete it. But if it is required, you should sort the elements by their key values.

For example if we have:

```
element 1 -> key= 101 , value= 6
element 2 -> key= 201 , value= 9
element 3 -> key= 301 , value= 2
```

you should not sort them as element 3 < element 1 < element 2
you should sort them like: element 1 < element 2 < element 3 in order to their key values.

In other words, if you want to sort them by their values, passing key values as a parameter is meaningless.